# passing jstl value to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

Hi I've the following code in jsp. I am trying to pass the value to javascript as follows. But it is not working.The code is as follows:

```
    <td><button name = "btn" onclick="callMe(<c:out value='${bus.vehicleId}'/>")>Show Details</button></td>
```

(Vehicle id is printing if I use  in my jsp.) Javascript is like this.

```
    function callMe(myId) {
        alert(myId);}
```

Here I am getting value as "undefined". I've tried in different way as follows

```
    <td><button name = "btn" onclick="callMe('${bus.vehicleId}')>Show tails</button></td>
```

This is also not working.Please help me asap.

Comment: Debug what you actually have in `${bus.vehicleId}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vehicleID might be string. If so, Yes! you get always undefined as a result. What ever the values coming as a result of `<c:out value='${bus.vehicleId}'/>` will be treated as a variable in html and javascript trying to print that variable value, which is `undefined`.

Try this way to let java script treat that jstl value as string literal

```
onclick="callMe('${bus.vehicleId}')">
```

Find single colon and double colons positions!

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class="txtnbmed">
<td align="center"><c:out value="${conPartRef.opCode}" /></td>
<td align="center"><html:select property="approvalStatus" indexed="true" name="conPartRef">
<option value="" <c:if test="${conPartRef.approvalStatus==''}">selected</c:if>>--- SELECT ---
<option value="A" <c:if test="${conPartRef.approvalStatus=='A'}">selected</c:if> >Approved
<option value="R" <c:if test="${conPartRef.approvalStatus=='R'}">selected</c:if> >Rejected
</option>
</html:select>
</td>
</c:forEach>

<input type="button" class="txtMF" value="Confirm & Print Supplement RO" onclick="doMarkAsOFP(this.form)">

function doMarkAsOFP(form) {
// need to get approvalStatus values and the opCode values.
submitPage();
}
```